# not able to show the data binded to select using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I have written the code to bind the data to select as follows

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: testData,value: selectedProjectID,optionsValue:'Id', optionsText: 'name'"></select>

function dataClass() {
viewmodel= this;
  this.testData = ko.observableArray([]);
 var array = [{ Id: "", name: "" }];
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(response.result, function (item, index) {
  array.push({ Id: item.objectId, name: item.name })
  array.join(',')
   });
   viewmodel.testData= JSON.stringify(array);
  // my data after json.stringify "[{"Id":"1","name":"Test"},{"Id":"2","name":"Test2"},]"
```

I am getting the required result but unable to show it in select can some one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `stringify` the array and more over there is no need of an extra array.You Can directly push items to `observableArray`.

```
function dataClass() {
  var viewmodel = this;
  viewmodel.testData = ko.observableArray([]);

  ko.utils.arrayForEach(response.result, function (item, index) {
     viewmodel.testData.push({ Id: item.objectId, name: item.name })
  });
}
```